# What's wrong with this JavaScript code? I'm trying to change the text of <h1> element on click

Tags: javascript, dom, onclick

I just started learning JavaScript.

I'm trying to change the text on a click.What's wrong with this code.
Please let me know.
Thanks

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<script>

function change_text(id)
{
 var arr = new Array("Now Click Again",""oops! Once more!","I'm Leaving!","Good Bye!");

 var x = Document.getElementById("heading");


 for(var i=0;i<arr.length;i++)
  x.innerHTML=arr[i];

 x.style.visibility="hidden";

 }
</script>

<h1 onclick="change_text()" id="heading">Click on this text!</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: There is an additional quote before 'ops' and "Document" is document, right?

Comment: The for loop also makes no sense in what you are trying to do.

Comment: Thanks @ViniciusLima, I've changed "Document" to "document' and removed that additional quote before 'oops'. Now on clicking , the text is vanishing.I think the for loop is not executing, what can I do now?

Comment: @epascarello , I'm trying to change the text of the <h1> element with the elements in the array "arr".

Comment: nikhil, my answer will work for what you're trying to do. @epascarello gets to the heart of the problem!

Comment: Thanks folks, for all your answers.I'm new to Scripting languages, I got used to control flow in programming languages.I'm getting used to  the control flow in JS.Thanks again for all ur replies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For one thing, you have two quotes here:

```
""oops! Once more!"
```

should be:

```
"oops! Once more!"
```

`Document` needs to be all lower-case (`document`).

`change_text(id)` is never used, and

`x.style.visibility="hidden"` needs to be moved outside the for loop.

You don't need a for loop at all, though, you just need to increment i++ every time the method is called, otherwise it will skip straight to "Goodbye".

```
<script>
var i = 0;
function change_text()
{
 var arr = new Array("Now Click Again","oops! Once more!","I'm Leaving!","Good Bye!");

 var x = document.getElementById("heading");


  i++;
  x.innerHTML=arr[i];
  if(i >= arr.length) {
        x.style.visibility="hidden";
  }

}

</script>
```

EDIT:
EDIT2: OK, you got the idea before!

Comment: Thanks Jimmy , It worked like charm. But can u explain me why for loop is not needed

Comment: :) no worries! You had exactly the right idea, it was mostly the for loop that was getting in the way, as @epascarello said. You needed to update the `i` variable once every time you called `change_text()`, while the for loop just updated `i` until it reached the end of the array.

Comment: I will edit my answer to try and explain as clearly as possible.

Comment: Jimmy,I got ur code. But,does the variable 'i' value persits between function calls?

Comment: Yeap, all variables will retain their values until you change them.

Comment: Thanks Jimmy,gone through your edits as well, that made it still clear.

Answer (score 0):

instead of "heading"

```
var x = Document.getElementById("heading");
```

you need to put the passed in value, id.

```
var x = Document.getElementById(id);
```

before this, you never actually use that id.

Also remember to pass that id in,

```
h1 onclick="change_text('heading')"
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this line;

```
var arr = new Array("Now Click Again",""oops! Once more!","I'm Leaving!","Good Bye!");
```

and this line

```
var x = Document.getElementById("heading");
```

to this;

```
var arr = new Array('Now Click Again','oops! Once more!','I\'m Leaving!','Good Bye!');
var x = document.getElementById(id);
```

Answer (score 0):

First, i don't know if it is a typo in your question but you have one extra " in your string array, this is how it should look.

```
var arr = new Array("Now Click Again","oops! Once more!","I'm Leaving!","Good Bye!");
```

And I don't know what you are trying to do with your for loop but the text you are showing will always be the last one in your array. Could you clarify what your are trying to achieve with the text in the h1 element?

Last of all, if you hide your element clearly your text won't show up, you should remove this line unless there is something I didn't understand correctly :

```
x.style.visibility="hidden";
```

Oh, and I think that your script element should have a type="text/javascript"

```
<script type="text/javascript">...
```

Unrelated to the question but if you can't spot the strings mistake in your array maybe you should change IDE. Even Notepad++ colors the strings, it might have helped you figure this one out.

Comment: I think the latest JavaScript standards, doesn't require this : type="text/javascript"